# Using crontab to run a .sh file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I am pretty new to Linux but I am trying to schedule a file to run using crontab.

The file runs perfectly when i type `./filename.sh` straight into the terminal but does not work with crontab

I want the file to run at 4:30 am daily so I put this

```
30 4 * * * /home/bots/Desktop/filename.sh
```

When I save the file, it outputs a text file with my text that was in the crontab but it doesn't execute the .sh file.

Is there anything i am doing wrong?

Sorry for sounding dumb, I'm just getting used to Linux.

Comment: Are you using an encrypted home directory?

Comment: what do you expect the script to do? How do you tell it didn't execute?

Comment: How are you editing the crontab? With `crontab -e`?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment to ask for detail so here are multiple possible explanations:

- The crontab you're using is `/etc/crontab`. In this case, the line you've added is invalid since it requires a user to run the task as (eg. `bots`) so it should look like this:

  `30 4 * * * bots /home/bots/Desktop/filename.sh`
- As suggested by Muru, you're using an encrypted `/home`, or any other reason which might cause the file to be unavailable.
- The `cron` daemon is disabled (unlikely but still).

If none of these work, post the logs of the `cron` daemon.